# Counting rows in left joined table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have 2 tables: users and log. Currently my query looks like that.

```
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT u.id, u.email, u.salt, u.pass, u.approved, u.ban, u2.status  FROM `users` AS u LEFT OUTER JOIN `log` AS u2 ON u2.user_id = u.id WHERE u.email = ?") or die($this->db->error);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['email']) or die($stmt->error);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
            die($this->ajax->respond(7));
        }
        $data = array();
        $stmt->bind_result($data['id'], $data['email'], $data['salt'], $data['pass'], $data['approved'], $data['ban'], $data['status']) or die($stmt->error);
        $stmt->fetch() or die($stmt->error);
        $stmt->close() or die($stmt->error);
```

Status column of log table - is indicates if user already signed in or not. What I want to do is to check if email exists in `users` table and to count rows of `log` table where `status=1`. Is that possible with one and only query?

In other words:

Here is log table

[image]

Take a look at rows where status = 1. This indicates that user 1 currently signed in. To prevent second signin from different browser I want to at first check for email in users table (basic signin procedure) and at that moment check if user not signed in (by counting rows where status = 1 in log table)

Comment: Can you provide the result you're expecting to get? Just some example data. Thanks

Comment: @MostyMostacho What I want to do is simple: I want to get count of status = 1 rows from log table as variable. If this variable > 0 will show error message and prevent login, if not then wil continue login process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the query to this -

```
SELECT u.id, u.email, u.salt, u.pass, u.approved, 
u.ban, SUM(u2.status) AS status FROM `users` AS u 
LEFT JOIN `log` AS u2 ON u2.user_id = u.id 
WHERE u.email = ?
GROUP BY u.id
```

There are a number of other ways to do this as well.

Comment: what this will `status` give me? count of rows where status=1 from log?

Comment: Yes - you can also do `COUNT(IF(u2.status = 1, 1, NULL)) AS status`, but that's more typing.